# plot a multiple rule function in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

How can I write the code for a function (complex contour) similar to this in Mathematica:
[image]

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean by a "function". Are you wanting to parametrize a contour for, say, purposes of numeric or symbolic integration? Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: @Daniel: I should have read your comment before I simply created the graphics....

Comment: @belisarius: You are right. I will try not forget to credit answers.

Comment: @Daniel: Actually I needed the graph of that parametric or polar function. by the way in general how can I write the code for the functions for example like this:  $f(x)=x^2, if x>=0; -x+1, if x<0$

Comment: @asd you can define that in many ways. For instance, `f[x_ /; x > 0] := x^2; f[x_ /; x < 0] := 1 - x;` does the job.

Comment: @asd Have a look at Piecewise[] in the Documentation Center. Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way is to use graphics primatives
(although I think I prefer Felix's `PolarPlot` solution)

```
With[{q = Pi/6}, 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {q, 2 Pi - q}], 
   Arrowheads[{{.05, .8}}], 
   Arrow[{{Cos[q] + 2, Sin[q]}, {Cos[q], Sin[q]}}], 
   Arrow[{{Cos[q], Sin[-q]}, {Cos[q] + 2, Sin[-q]}}],
   FontSize -> Medium, Text["\[ScriptCapitalC]", {2, Sin[q]}, {0, -2}]}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 6}, {-4, 4}}]]
```

[image: contour]

I guess if you want the actual function for contour, then maybe something like

```
contour[t_, t0_: (5 Pi/6)] := Piecewise[{
   {Exp[I (t + Pi)], -t0 < t < t0},
   {t - t0 + Exp[I (t0 + Pi)], t >= t0},
   {-t - t0 + Exp[-I (t0 + Pi)], t <= -t0}}]

ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[contour[t]]], {t, -8, 8}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: contour v2]

And to add arrows to this plot, I guess you'd have to add them in manually (using `Epilog` or the drawing tools) or use one of the packages that modifies the built-in plots.

Answer (score 5):

I am not exactly sure what c is, but I assumed it was a number between 0 and 1 meaning the height of the incoming straight line. So maybe somehting like this would suit your needs?

```
c = 0.7;
t0 = ArcSin[c];
PolarPlot[If[Abs[t] < t0, Abs[Sin[t0]/Sin[t]], 1], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: I'd guess `c` is just a label (it's the contour of integration c, as it's usually called in books etc). You could very easily add arrows to your contour using this package: http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html

Comment: Arrow & labeling can also be added using something like the Epilog below ...
Epilog -> {
  Arrow[{{2, c}, {1, c}}], Arrow[{{1, -c}, {2, -c}}],
  Arrow[{{-1, .1}, {-1, -.1}}],
  Text["C", {1.5, c + .1}],
  Text["C", {1.5, -(c + .1)}]
  }